# I would like others to explain how can i display video from rectangle to parallelogram in c# to me

Tags: c#, video

Does someone know if it's possible to display a video in a form deformed? I mean not in a rectangle but in a parallelogram.

If it's not possible, is possible to mask a part of video? So I can put another video under it?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

With your favourite 3d-Rendering-API, you would render to a texture and then use this texture on a quad.

You could of course also do it by hand, copy each scanline, and for each scanline, you increase the distance to the left or right a bit.